# Handling both XML and JSON response from CXF FaultOutInterceptor

Tags: java, cxf, handler, jax-rs, interceptor

As I have noticed, in my `CXF JaxRS service`,  if I throw an exception in say `READ phase` (`IN interceptor`) and do not provide any default `FaultOutInterceptor`, the `XMLFaultOutInterceptor` takes care of building the response as it should be returned `(which is always an XML)`.

Now, I would like to be able to return a response in the format in which the service was requested : JSON or XML or otherwise.

I found something like this on the web:

```
public class JsonFaultOutHandlerInterceptor extends JAXRSOutInterceptor
{
    public JsonFaultOutHandlerInterceptor() {
        getBefore().add(LoggingOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        ...
        message.getInterceptorChain().abort();
    }
}
```

I have configured it in the `outInterceptor`, should I conditionally abort (if the request type was `application/Json`) or not abort(if the request type was `application/xml`) the interceptor chain? (I'm not sure if the request type information is already available. Also, somehow, aborting the chain doesn't seem very correct)

Had the response reached the `JAXRS filters`, using `ExceptionMapper<T>` I would have beautifully handled the response. But when the exception occurs in the `INinterceptor`, I am a little lost.

What would be a good way to be able to define a `FaultOutInterceptor`?